# Load php class extend by request

Tags: php

I have two classes:

```
class Init {
     public function test() {
          echo 1;
     }

     public static function loadSecond() {
          // Load the class
     }
}

class Second extends Init {
     public function test2() {
          echo 2;
     }
}
```

I need to load `Second` class only by request. For example:

```
$init = new Init();
$init->test();

$second = $init::loadSecond();
$second->test2();
```

Comment: what do you mean by request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need to do.
If you mean to include a class whenever you need it automatically :

As Marcin Orlowski mentionned it, what you need is to use the autoloading function of PHP.

Basically it should look like :

```
function __autoload ($name)
{
    include "/path/to/my/includes/" . $name . "inc.php";
}
```

If you mean creating an object from another class, you should probably do like

```
class Init {
     public function test() {
          echo 1;
     }

     public static function loadSecond() {
          return new Second;
     }
}

class Second extends Init {
     public function test2() {
          echo 2;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `// Load the class` with

`return new Second()`

You just need to create a new object. (I do not know why you need it to be that way, but this should  work for your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is class autoloading feature implemented. It's basically supported by PHP, so follow the docs: http://php.net/manual/pl/language.oop5.autoload.php